# Python If Statements - Display numeric Results

Tags: python, if-statement

I am writing a python code that returns me the larger of two inputs.

```
def bigger_num(a, b):
    if a < b:
        print ("First number is smaller than the second number.")
    elif a > b:
        print ("First number is greater than the second number.")
    else:
        print ("Two numbers are equals.")
        
a = input("Enter first number: ")
a = float(a)

b = input("Enter second number : ")
b = float(b)
print(bigger_num(a, b))
```

```
Result:
Enter first number: 19
Enter second number : 9
First number is greater than the second number.
None
```

How do I display the numeric result (a/b) in the print?

Ideal solution example: First number, 19 is greater than the second number

Also, is there a way to remove none from the print result?

Comment: Simplest: `print ("First number", a, "is smaller than the second number", b)`

Comment: You need to look for a python beginners course... but good luck and welcome to Python!

Comment: Just call `bigger_num(a, b)` without surrounding `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `format()` method or simply concatenate the number to display it. To remove the `None`, just call the function without the wrapping it with a `print()` because you print the output inside the function

```py
def bigger_num(a, b):
    if a < b:
        print ("First number, {0} is smaller than the second number.".format(a))
    elif a > b:
        print ("First number, {0} is greater than the second number.".format(a))
    else:
        print ("Two numbers are equals.")
        
a = input("Enter first number: ")
a = float(a)

b = input("Enter second number : ")
b = float(b)
bigger_num(a, b)
```

Comment: From python 3.6 you can use [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). In this example, `f"First number, {a} is smaller than the second number."` for the first conditional.